# cx_freeze python 310 Permission denied in "traitlets-5.2.2.post1.dist-info\\license_files" using windows

Tags: python, permissions, cx-freeze

I'm trying to build a excetufable from cx_freeze using the following setup.py in windows 10:

```py
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
exe = Executable(
    script=r"WCA_TOOL.py",
    base="Win32GUI",
    )

setup(
    name = "TESTApp",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "An example",
    executables = [exe]
    )
```

And when I run the setup.py, the cmd (in administrator mode) print the following message:

```
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: \\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\traitlets-5.2.2.post1.dist-info\\license_files'
```

What can I do ?

Comment: Could you double-check the indentation of your code?

Comment: Sorry the indentation of my code was wrong only in this post !

Answer (score 1):

It happend to me too. And it will be ok if I comment the package "PIL".

At last I found that "PIL.Image" and "ipython" was not compatible,

so I remove "ipython" and it worked.

The other way is install the lower version cx-freeze.

```
pip uninstall cx-freeze -y
pip install cx-freeze==6.10
```